# Hibernate keep old data

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm beginer in Hibernate and Spring MVC, and i have a repetitive problem on retrieving data, sometimes when i refresh my page or just submit a form, i get old data that i had updated or even deleted.

Here is my configurations file of hibernate :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
 <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cotaDB18</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <!-- <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property> -->

    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">4</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

</session-factory>
```

I retrieve data like this :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Tache> getTachesByPhase(int idPhase) {
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String hql = "From Tache T where T.phase=" + idPhase + " Order by T.index";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    return query.list();
}
```

Please i need your help, i don't find the solution

Comment: You also need to show us how you retreive this data.

Comment: I think this happens when HTTP-POST scope is not broken. Seldom when you refresh your page the old computation you did also gets a refresh. Is that the problem you are facing?

Comment: @DarshanLila Yes that's it ! is not common but generaly it happens when i refresh or submit a form with a post method

Comment: @RandomSeed here is the method of retrieving data